# Laravel middleware throw a "No supported encrypter found" message

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, encryption, laravel-artisan

in laravel 5.2
simply, this code works greate:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
if(Auth::guest())
{
    return Redirect::to('login');
}
else
{
    return view('index');   
}

});
```

and this code doesn't work and throws the message of "No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid."

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
//

Route::get('/',function(){
    return view('index');
})->middleware('auth');
});
```

even when I tested the default artisan make:auth of laravel it still shows the same message.
I don't think it is a key thing because I can login using the first method but can't use middleware.
help...

**UPDATE:**
the key is the same 32 chars key in both .env file and config/app.php file , and 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'

**UPDATE 2**
After Help and checking the Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php I found out that:

```
$config = $app->make('config')->get('app');
$key = $config['key'];
$cipher = $config['cipher'];
```

and when I tried to echo the $cipher value I found it to be 'AES-256-CBC' just like in the config file but the $key variable is null. so why wouldn't it read the key from the config file or from the .env file???

Comment: In your .env file, do you have the `APP_KEY` var set?

Comment: yes, the same 32 chars key in both .env file and config/app.php file , and 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'

Comment: Create a page with `phpinfo()`, do you see a `mcrypt` section?

Comment: mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support enabled

Comment: In `Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider` try `dd`ing the `$key` and `$cipher` vars and make sure they are what you expect.

Comment: I tried to change these variables with strings variables just like it is in the .env but I get a new problem ... call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth' does not have a method 'handle'

Comment: well, partly your suggestion works, the key in the EnctyptionServiceProvider is null so I manually wrote it as a string, and the other problem is that I wrote ->middleware('Auth') with a capital "A" but it has to be ->middleware('auth') with a small "a". now the problem is that it feels odd to manually write the key why couldn't it grab it from the config file or the .env file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the App.php file there is this:

```
'key' => env('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

which should be

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

or

```
'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: or 'key' => env('APP_KEY')        .  That way it will take the value from .env